# Ant: Convert comma-delimited list of relative paths to path

Tags: ant

I have a comma-delimited list of directories:

```
foo,bar,baz,qux
```

I want to convert it to an Ant path containing (something like) the following:

```
${basedir}/build/foo/classes
${basedir}/build/bar/classes
${basedir}/build/baz/classes
${basedir}/build/qux/classes
```

It seems like there should be a way to do this with `<pathconvert>`, but it's not obvious to me what it would be. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a [`dirset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) to hold your list of directories, then feed that into pathconvert.  Something like:

```
<property name="dirs" value="foo,bar,baz,qux" />
<dirset id="dir_list" dir="${basedir}" includes="${dirs}" />

<pathconvert refid="dir_list" property="dirs_prop">
    <regexpmapper from="(${basedir})/(.*)" to="\1/build/\2/classes" />
</pathconvert>
```

Then the property `${dirs_prop}` will hold the path you want... or almost.  The problem with `dirset` is that the order of directories is not defined.  To retain the order of the original list, use a [`filelist`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html) in place of the `dirlist`:

```
<filelist id="dir_list" dir="${basedir}" files="${dirs}" />
```