# Write a foreach for putting pathelements inside classpath element

Tags: ant, classpath, ant-contrib

I have a property holding comma separated file paths which i need to add to ant classpath for running a class.
I want to iterate over the list and place values in pathelement one by one?
Something like this

```
<classpath> 
foreach path in paths
   <pathElement location="${path}"/>
foreach
</classpath>
```

But from what i know is ant-contrib [foreach](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) cannot be used inside classpath element.
Please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant: Convert comma-delimited list of relative paths to path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025602/ant-convert-comma-delimited-list-of-relative-paths-to-path)

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025602/ant-convert-comma-delimited-list-of-relative-paths-to-path will help you.  ant-contrib is never the solution, unless your problem is a build file that is too readable.

Answer (score 0):

Would be a lot simpler to use a fileset to populate your paths:

```
<path id="compile.path">
  <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

And use this in your build as a classpath reference:

```
<javac ... classpathref="compile.path"/>
```